# If statement without '&&' works?

Tags: c++, expression-evaluation

```
int n = 5;    
if(2<=n<=20) 
 {
  cout << "hello";
 }
```

In the above code, it does not give an error, it runs successfully and gives "hello" as output.

But we have to use `&&` in this kind of equation.
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Can you give us a hint about the type of `n`, is it an `int`?

Comment: Re: "gives "hello" as output" -- for certain values of `n`, but not limited to values in the range `[2..20]`. Try it.

Comment: n is an integer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`<=` is left-associative in C++, so the expresion is parsed as `((2 <= n) <= 20)`. `2 <= n` is of type `bool`, which can implicitly convert to `int`: `true` converts to `1` and `false` converts to `0`.

Both of these are `<= 20`, so the condition is effectively always true.

---

Note that the above assumes `n` is an `int` or another primitive numerical type. If `n` is a user-defined class with `operator <=` overloaded, the associativity bit is still true, but the part about implicit conversions may or may not apply, based on the return type and semantics of that overloaded operator.

Comment: Will anything change when `n` is some other primitive type, like a `double`?

Comment: @Gassa No, but it will change if `n` is a class type. Answer extended.

Comment: @Angew: It holds for any primitive type n, including floating point NaN.

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, a NaN is still of a numerical type. It wouldn't work for pointers.

Comment: @Angew: Good point. Have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

`2<=n<=20`  will be executed as `(2<=n)<=20`.

`2<=n` results in `0` or `1`, depending on the value of `n`.

`0<=20` and `1<=20` are true, so the `cout` will be executed, independent of the value and type of `n`.

`n` could be an object of a class with overloaded operators where `2<=n` results to something (object to a class or a value `>21`), which compared with `<=20` results to `false`. In this case there would be no output.

Comment: independent of the type of `n` ? I am not so sure about that

Answer (score 1):

You probably mean

```
if (2 <= n && n <= 20)
```

C++ and C group `2 <= n <= 20` as `(2 <= n) <= 20`; the sub-expression is either 0 (`false` in C++) or 1 (`true`), which are both less than or equal to 20, hence the entire expresion is 1 (`true`). This is true for *any* primitive non-pointer type `n`, including a floating point NaN.

Answer (score 0):

The first comparison `2 <= n` is evaluated first. This returns `true`, which is convertible to an `int`. From [conv.integral#2](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.integral#2):

> If the source type is `bool`, the value `false` is converted to zero and the value `true` is converted to one.

Once `true` is converted to `1` or `0`, the next comparison is `1 <= 20` or `0 <= 20` which is always true. Hence the output.

Comment: Nitpick: `2 <= n` might be `false` as well.

Comment: @Gassa Generally true, but in the question: "[...] and gives "hello" as output".

Comment: As I see it, that's because the second comparison is true, not the first one.

Comment: Wait, now **I** see it, you're right of course :)